# How do I show that my object is loading before it actually loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, loader

I currently have this:

```
$(window).load ->

  $('#image-gallery').lightSlider
    gallery: true
    item: 1
    thumbItem: 7
    slideMargin: 0
    loop: true
```

But the issue is that my `lightSlider` is loading in the wrong position when the page is not fully loaded. After page loads completely, the slider fixes itself.

How do I make sure that my loader image shows first and then it will load this snippet after the slider is ready?

EDIT

Sorry, I meant I wanted to show a loading gif before the image is shown

```
#pre-loading
  = image_tag "ajax-loader.gif"
%ul#image-gallery
  - @go.go_images.each do |image|
    %li{ data: { thumb: image.photo_url(:small), src: image.photo_url(:small)} }
      = image_tag image.photo_url(:large)
```

So I'm trying to show the `#pre-loading` div prior to showing `%ul#image-gallery`. My coffeescript is correct, but the issue is that the slider is loading too fast, and it's not in the right position when it loads. I want to hide the slider, show the preloader, and when the slider is fully loaded after the entire page is completely done loading, then show the slider.

Comment: Please help us help you by showing some complete code instead of code portions that will never run without errors.

Comment: Just FYI that's coffeescript and will run fine, although your point about seeing a complete code example is valid.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "not fully loaded" -- in theory the jQuery .load() will wait for images to be loaded before firing, but in reality, its unreliable due to browser differences and caching. You might need to try and detect "loaded" in another way, depending which elements need to be "loaded" for your slider to work properly.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace I've edited, hopefully its more clear

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah ok. Havent don't much work with that so didn't recognize it and it wasn't tagged at the time I made the comment. Only saw js and jquery.

Comment: Hah ok your question seemed totally different before the edit. You'll need to lean on your slider plugin to tell you when its ready. Before that, hide your gallery element, wrap it in an element that has the loader gif as a background image. When your gallery plugin tells you its ready, show its container element (should sit on TOP of your loader gif).